# sending array from android to php

Tags: php, android, arrays

I have an array

```
ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and few strings

```
 private String sq,tr;
```

am sending these values to  a remote server via POST request

```
 nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
 nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sq", sq));
 nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tr", tr));
 nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sub[]", selectedItems);
```

My problem is am able to send strings but when I try to send the array am getting errors

Please suggest me the best way to send array as well as strings via post method or guide me if am making some mistake.

Answer (score 0):

try to put that in loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sub[]",selectedItems[i]));
}
```

Comment: maybe `"sub[" + i + "]"` should be used instead of `"sub[]"`

Comment: "sub[" + i + "]" with result seperate fields appear rather than a array.

Comment: nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sub[]",selectedItems[i])); makes all value appear in single field aka array field.